# Get finish date, given start date and schedule in week

Tags: php, date, dayofweek

I have a problem using PHP to get the finish date of course, as below:

**Inputs:**

- Start date (e.g: `8/23/2019`)
- Schedule in week (e.g: `Monday, Tuesday, Friday`)
- Total of lessons (e.g: `8`)

**Output:** The finish date of course (is `9/9/2019` with above e.g inputs).

One lesson is one day. Input fields from end user:
[image: Input fields from end user]

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you very much!

Comment: what fields you have inputs from user end?????

Comment: @MohitKumar, I've just update input fields from end user in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it loop while there are lessons left and subtract when it's Monday, Tuesday or Friday.
After the loop output the date.

```
$start = "8/23/2019";
$days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"];
$n = 8;

$d = strtotime($start);
while($n>0){
    //See if day is in days array
    if(in_array(date("l", $d), $days)){
        $n--;
    }
    $d += 86400; // go to next day
}

echo date("m/d/Y", $d-86400); //-86400 because  the loop adds one at the end.
```

Comment: Oh, very short and clearly. I think it's the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, if I understand you correctly))

```
<?
$startDay = '2019-09-25';
$aSchedule = array(1,2,4);
$iCntShed = count($aSchedule);
$iLessonsCnt = 8;
$iDWStartDay = date('w',strtotime($startDay));
$aDOWMap = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');

// first day according Schedule array and startDay
$aWeekDays = array_filter($aSchedule,function($iSDW) use ($iDWStartDay){
    return $iSDW>= $iDWStartDay;
});

// day according of week
$nextDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDay.' next '.$aDOWMap[end($aWeekDays)]));
$i = 0;

while (count($aWeekDays)<$iLessonsCnt) {
    $i = $i<$iCntShed ? $i : 0;
    $aWeekDays[] = $aSchedule[$i];
    $nextDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($nextDate.' next '.$aDOWMap[$aSchedule[$i++]]));
}

print_r($aWeekDays);

echo $nextDate;
```